# Display two textBlock on a dataGrid

Tags: wpf, panel, datatemplate

Is there possibility to display two TextBlock on a Grid ?

I tried, but i see only my first TextBlock.

Here is my XAML code :

```
                <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTiers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"> 
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="#FFDEDEDE" CornerRadius="10" Margin="10">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Grid Height="89" Width="975">
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCode}" Margin="12,23,479,30" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" Margin="501,23,14,24" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"/>
                                </Grid>                                                  
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

Grid is the best UI container which supports orientation. You can modify your code in the below way.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxTiers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"> 
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Background="#FFDEDEDE" CornerRadius="10" Margin="10">
                            <Grid Height="89" Width="975">
                       <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBox_CodeTiers" Grid.Column=0 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strCode}" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBox_NomTiers" Grid.Column=1 TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding m_strNom}"/>
                            </Grid> 
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

You should have to adjust the column column width as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your texts are drawn at the same location.
You can either add Grid columns/Raws or remove the grid completly and stay with the stackPanel

You should go over [Panels Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152.aspx)

Comment: i tried to make the code with Blend. Could you give me the code please, in order to understand ? Thanks :)

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni I have added a link to msdn article it contains examples

Comment: Thanks, a lot, so, if i would to display two or three textbox in the same line of a listbox. What's yout advice please ? A grid ? Two grid ? I'm a bit lost, even with the MSDN ;(

Comment: @WalterFabioSimoni the answer would change depending your specific UI requirements, start with stackPanel....